# Create a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables: [Tables link](http://s2.postimg.org/tsr11vq61/Diagram1.png)

And I need to create query that returns **Payment_ID, the TICKET ID or BILL ID (it depends on the type) in which the Salesman ID is '02'**.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
select p.payment_id, p.id_ticket, p.id_bill
from Payment as p, Ticket as t, Bill as b
where p.id_ticket=t.id_ticket
and p.id_bill=b.id_bill
and and t.id_salesman in ('02')
and b.id_salesman in ('02')
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `and and`? are you sure?

Comment: @Sebas yeah, I mean, I guess. How it should be then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.payment_id, p.id_ticket, p.id_bill
from Payment as p, Ticket as t, Bill as b
where p.id_ticket=t.id_ticket
and p.id_bill=b.id_bill
and t.id_salesman in ('02')
and b.id_salesman in ('02')
```

you also need to join `ticket` with `bill`  something like:

`ticket.id = bill.id`

Comment: I have to? even if those two tables are not related?

Comment: @SergioVera the way your query is written yes.

Comment: no, I related the ID's that payment has with ticket and bill, but not bill and ticket with each other: http://s2.postimg.org/tsr11vq61/Diagram1.png